# git rebase fails with "'ebase-merge' is not recognized..."

Tags: git, rebase

I'm using git version.2.7.1.windows.2. When I issue the git rebase command below, I get the error message below. This happens in more than one clone on my computer, and with more than one unrelated branches. It does not happen using the same branches on a different computer. The message says that my branch was successfully rebased, but it is actually unchanged.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

```
C:\dev\myClone [mids ↑]> git rebase -i HEAD~3
'ebase-merge' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/mids.
```

Comment: I uninstalled git and reinstalled (version 2.8.3 this time). I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was just a problem with trying to launch Atom to edit the text file to specify how to do the rebase. I "unset" my text editor setting

```
git config --global --unset core.editor
```

and now it defaults to vi, and I'm able to rebase.

Comment: I had the same problem and also just figured this out. I switched to VS Code and it works.